# Set size of java element using AWT

Tags: java, awt, components, element

I am new to java. I have started learning java 1 day ago.. I am background of c++ (not very good 1 year of intermadiate exp). In java we have started Gui programming. So i would like to ask you how can i set size of java components (button textbox radiobutton etc..) **using only AWT library**. I dont want to use **swing library** because the my teacher has not speak about this yet. Give me simple example.

I am trying something like this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Color;
class java0{
    public static void main (String argv[]){
        int a,b,c;
        Color CCC = Color.decode("#ff4500");

        Frame window = new Frame("First window");

        Panel cont = new Panel();
        cont.setBackground(CCC);

        TextField txfld = new TextField();

        Button btn = new Button("Run");
        btn.setSize(200,200); //this is not working..
        btn.setLocation(50,50);//neither this.
        cont.add(btn);
        window.add(cont);
        window.setSize(500,500);
        window.setLocation(400,300);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setBounds() instead of setSize().

Comment: yes but does not works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not your fault. AWT is a mess and completely non-intuitive.

try this

```
    Button btn = new Button("Run");
    btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200)); <------
    btn.setLocation(50,50);//neither this.
    cont.add(btn);
    window.add(cont);
    window.setSize(500,500);
    window.setLocation(400,300);
    window.pack(); <------
    window.setVisible(true);
```

About position, you must take a look on how layouts work in Java

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html